# How fast can we solve a totally unimodular integer linear program?

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, linear-programming, integer-programming, polynomial-time

(This is a follow-up to [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/4409/148)  and its [answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4409/which-integer-linear-programs-are-easy/4411#4411).)

I have the following totally unimodular (TU) integer linear program (ILP). Here  $\ell,m,n_{1},n_{2},\ldots,n_{\ell},c_{1},c_{2},\ldots,c_{m},w$ are all positive integers given as part of the input. A specified subset of the variables $x_{ij}$ is set to zero, and the rest can take positive integral values:

> Minimize
>
> $\sum_{j=1}^{m}c_{j}\sum_{i=1}^{\ell}x_{ij}$
>
> Subject to:
>
> $\sum_{j=1}^{m}x_{ij}=n_{i}\,\,\forall i$
>
> $\sum_{i=1}^{\ell}x_{ij}\ge w\,\,\forall j$

The coefficient matrix of the standard form is a $(2\ell+m)\times \ell m$ matrix with entries from ${-1,0,1}$.

My question is:

> What are the best upper bounds known for the running time of polynomial-time algorithms that solve such an ILP? Could you point me to some references on this?

I did some searching, but at most places they stop with saying that a TU ILP can be solved in polynomial time using polynomial-time algorithms for LP. One thing that looked promising is a 1986 paper by Tardos [1] where she proves that such problems can be solved in time polynomial in the size of the coefficient matrix. As far as I could figure out from the paper, however, the running time of that algorithm depends in turn on the running time of a polynomial-time algorithm for solving LP.

> Do we know of algorithms that solve this special case (of TU ILP) significantly faster than the general algorithms that solve the LP problem?

If not,

> Which algorithm for LP would solve such an ILP the fastest (in an asymptotic sense)?

[1] A strongly polynomial algorithm to solve combinatorial linear programs, Eva Tardos, Operations Research 34(2), 1986

Comment: As pointed out by the answer you cite to your previous post, your problem is a special case of the transportation problem, which is in turn a special case of minimum-cost flow.  See [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5918/what-is-the-currently-best-known-algorithm-for-the-transportation-problem) and [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/30525/fastest-polynomial-time-algorithm-for-solving-minimum-cost-maximum-flow-problems) for posts asking for fast algorithms for these two problems.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe [On a class of totally unimodular matrices](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdfplus/3689380.pdf?acceptTC=true), by Yannakakis, gives an answer to your question for a special case of TU ILP (whenever there are no odd cycles in a bipartite graph obtained by seeing the coefficient matrix as an adjacency matrix).

In that paper there is a reference to [Polynomial algorithms for a class of linear programs](http://www.springerlink.com/content/j0m40587pj827586/fulltext.pdf), which seems to handle all totally unimodular matrices, but I am not sure about how much more efficient it is compared to generic algorithms for LPs.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to derive better bounds from the general LP algorithm in the paper "Linear Programming in $O([n^3/\ln n]L)$ Operations" ([here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S1052623497323194)).

Answer (score 1):

It has been shown that totally unimodular LP is solvable in strongly polynomial time under a "degeneracy assumption" -  [link here](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/10556788.2016.1208748) (thus if the ILP has a Totally Unimodular (TU) formulation with the same assumptions then this algorithm would solve 
a TU ILP, in strong polynomial time. This is a development from Tardos's methods, and implies tighter bounds to an TU (Totally Unimodular) ILP formulation.