# What is the currently best known algorithm for the transportation problem?

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, graph-algorithms

Consider the well known transportation problem:
There are $m$ supply nodes, $n$ demand nodes and $k$ feasible arcs. 
Every node has a integer supply or demand, and the arcs have integer costs, used linearly, i.e. if $x$ units are shipped along an edge annotated with $c$, the cost is $c\cdot x$.

I have an article by [Kleinschmidt and Schannath](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01585755) describing an $O(m\log m (k+n\log n))$ solution.

**Is this the currently best algorithm, or has there been an improvement since 1995?**

(My search turned up an article by [Brenner](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.orl.2008.01.011) from 2008, but I don't have access to it.  The title talks about the "unbalanced Hitchcock transportation problem", I am not sure it is the problem considered here).

Would this be the right algorithm to implement?

Which libraries provide implementations of the transportation problem?

Comment: do you need integer transportation or is fractional transportation ok (because the latter is the EMD, is it not ?)